# Python. Как задать вопрос у пользователя, хочет ли он повторить программу? C несколькими вариантами ответа

Tags: python, list, input, if, while

**Вот примерный код. И я хочу, чтобы не было только 2 варианта - (Да/Нет), а намного больше, как тут:**

```
list_yes = ["yes", "y", "да", "д", "YES", "Y", "ДА", "Д", "+", "++", "+++", "++++", "++++", "конечно", "КОНЕЧНО"]

while True:
    returns_2 = input('Ещё раз? [да/нет]: ')
    if returns_2 == list_yes:
        convert()
    else:
        break
print(Fore.YELLOW)
exit = input("Нажмите ENTER, чтобы закрыть программу: ")
```

И ещё вопрос, а имеет разница, если пользователь будет заглавными буквами писать ответ, или строчными?

Comment: Заглавные или строчные да разница есть но можно привести к одному виду. А в чем вопрос то? `намного больше, как тут`  так готово же все...

Comment: Прикол в том, что оно не работает, и пишется: "Нажмите ENTER, чтобы закрыть программу" Просто игнорируется, в итоге я так и не понял, в чём проблема.

Comment: Вы сравниваете строку со списком. Условие `if` всегда ложное => вас перекидывает на else => цикл ломается на первой итерации. Измените `==` на `in`.

Comment: **Спасибо!!!!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не совсем понял вопрос, если я праввильно его обработал - ответ:

Создайте еще list_no с "нет ответами"
и вот так

```py
if returns_2 in list_yes:
    pass
elif returns_2 in list_no:
    pass
else:
    continue
```

`==` Сравнивает ответ со списком (Не верно)

`in` Переводится как "В" (Есть ли ответ в списке) (Верно)

`pass` Не делать ничего (поставил для примера)

`continue` Делает итерацию цикла и задаёт вопрос сначала

Что бы принимать и строчные и заглавные:
Сделайте в списке все слова маленькими буквами и исправьте:

```
input('Ещё раз? [да/нет]: ')
```

На:

```
str(input('Ещё раз? [да/нет]: ')).lower()
```

Ответ пользователя будет записан маленькими буквами и будет сравниматься тоже с маленькими буквами